# Control buttons missing after flash published Adobe Flash cs6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been trying do do what I thought would be very simple, but so far each time I publish the flash file on Adobe Flash cs6, I do not see the control panel below the vid with the start/pause, timeline, volume, full-screen buttons/controls. They are always missing.

Using adobe flash cs6 I create a new fla file, import an flv vid into it, then choose a pre-selected control 'skin'. It is like the most basic thing you can do.

Once I do that, the volume controls appear where they should, just below the vid, in the 'Scene' window of adobe flash before i attempt to publish it to the swf file (so i can use it on the web)

That is all I want. Import the vid, get the controls, and publish.

When I publish, the vid works fine but the control panel / bar is missing. I have uploaded all the files produced by Adobe Flash cs6 that resulted from the publication to the server. Everything is in the same folder.

The resulting html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>vid2</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
    body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
    #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flashContent">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="375" height="260" id="vid2" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="vid2.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="vid2.swf" width="375" height="260">
                <param name="movie" value="vid2.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
```

But no control panel

Comment: do you have a flvplayback in your swf file???

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It took me too long to figure it out. I changed the player.